# Have drone hover for longer than 32,767ms after completing waypoint in DJIWaypointMission

Tags: dji-sdk

In the iOS [DJI documentation for DJIWaypointActionType](https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/ios-api/Components/Missions/DJIWaypoint_DJIWaypointAction.html?search=djiwaypointactino&i=2&#djiwaypoint_djiwaypointactiontype_inline), it states that the maximum range for `DJIWaypointActionTypeStay` is 32767ms. I need a drone to hover for 60s or more. Is there a way around this limitation?

I've attempted implement this manually using the Timeline. This would be much preferred for our use case. However, I need to pause the timeline *in between* each action, not during any given action. Is there a way to do that? Attempting to pause the timeline results in errors which the debugger showing have codes 10003 and 10060. Retrieving these errors with `NSError.djisdkMissionError(forCode: 10003)` yields `UnknownError` for both codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to separate each action into it's own Timeline consisting of only one elemnt. Then, after each timeline is complete, reinitialize the mission control object before executing the next timeline.

Answer (score 0):

How about using hover at last waypoint?

Comment: Could you elaborate or link to documentation?

Comment: WaypointMissionFinishedAction has an option NO_ACTION, this leaves the aircraft hovering at the last WP until you do something to move it.  You would need to manage the timer in the app but it will sit there forever (or until batteries require RTH/Landing).  It's not as good as a wait and continue but it will get you what you want.  You cannot set the pause longer because the variable type is limited to the 32767